# Send fetchAll array via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this method that retrieves a list of dates from my database.

```
function getdate($id) {
    $select = $this->db->query("select * from dates where user_id= '$id' ");
    $row = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    return $row;        
}
```

And I have a model file "load calendar.php" which calls the method getdate:

```
    $dates = $user->getdate($id);
    echo $dates;
```

I want to be able to store the array $dates in an array my js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dbdates = new Array();
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'loadcalendar.php',
             data: { dates:dates },
             success: function(response) {
                 dbdates = response;
                 alert(dbdates);

          }

      });
```

However, when I alert dbdates, nothing comes out. My 'getdate' method works. I only need help with the Ajax call. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should print `response` to the console instead of using an alert after you're trying to save it into your array. You need to make sure you're even getting a response before using the data.

Comment: You should check that `$dates` array contains data with `print_r`. To send the data, consider using `json_encode` (in PHP) and `JSON.parse(response)` (in JS)

Comment: Double check that you're getting a response back from the API through your browser's Network tab. Moreover, try and `console.log` the response instead of alerting them. You could use `$.parseJSON` to convert returned string response into JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyze these statements here,

```
$dates = $user->getdate($id);
echo $dates;
```

`getdate()` method actually returns an array, and what you're trying to do with `echo $dates;` is, you're trying to convert an array to a string, which won't work.

Instead, `json_encode` the array and `echo` it, like this:

```
$dates = $user->getdate($id);
echo json_encode($dates);
```

Also, add `dataType: 'json'` setting in your AJAX request, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dbdates = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'loadcalendar.php',
        data: { dates:dates },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            dbdates = response;
            console.log(dbdates);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked . I now get an array in this form: Array
(
    [0] => 09-23-2016
    [1] => 09-20-2016
    [2] => 09-21-2016 )     Do you know how I can convert it to an array of strings ['09-23-2016','09-20-2016 ... ]

Comment: @S.Al Oh, I commented too soon. Yes, you can do that using `toString()` method, like this: `new Array(dbdates.toString())`